# Extract list of data from PDF that repeats using Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have PDF that has sections that is similar in structure but the data differs. The sections are not detected as table. Each sections have multiple data to be read. And I would need to get all the values for all sections as array. And the number of section varies with invoice. How do I achieve that.